# Why is it not possible to instantiate pair with "non const" copy constructor while it is possible to instantiate one without?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

Suppose you have the following class:

```
struct A {
    A () {}
    A (A &) = delete;
};

int main() {
    std::pair<A, int> p1;
    return 0;
}
```

The following code will fail to compile (using `-std=c++11` with `g++`) with the following error:

> /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of ‘struct std::pair’:
>
> test.cpp:13:23:   required from here
>
> /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:127:17: error: ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = A; _T2 = int]’ declared to take const reference, but implicit declaration would take non-const
>
> ```
> constexpr pair(const pair&) = default;
> ```

According to the error message, I would assume that this is because it is not possible to instanciate the default copy constructor because of the `const` qualifier on the `std::pair` argument.

I could understand why this would not compile without the `= delete`, because it is not possible to instanciate the copy constructor which takes a `std::pair const&` parameter.

But with the `= delete`, I would expect the compiler to not instantiate such constructor because it cannot (as far as I understand). Actually, this copy constructor is deleted as shown by this piece of code:

```
std::pair<A, int> p1;
decltype(p1) p2(p1);
```

Which fails:

> test.cpp:11:23: error: use of deleted function ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = A; _T2 = int]’
>
> ```
> decltype(p1) p2(p1);
> ```

Basically, my question is: Why does the compiler fails to instantiate a deleted copy constructor of `std::pair`?

Comment: See http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-closed.html#2068

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[[class.copy]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy#8):

> The implicitly-declared copy constructor for a class `X` will have the
>   form
>
> ```
> X::X(const X&)
> ```
>
> if each potentially constructed subobject of a class type `M` (or
>   array thereof) has a copy constructor whose first parameter is of type
>   `const M&` or `const volatile M&`. Otherwise, the implicitly-declared
>   copy constructor will have the form
>
> ```
> X::X(X&)
> ```

Therefore, if the copy constructor of `std::pair<A, int>` were to be implicitly declared, it would have the form `pair::pair(pair &)`.

[[dcl.fct.def.default]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.default#1):

> A function that is explicitly defaulted shall
>
> - be a special member function,
> - have the same declared function type (except for possibly differing *ref-qualifier*s and except that in the case of a copy constructor or
>     copy assignment operator, the parameter type may be “reference to
>     non-const `T`”, where `T` is the name of the member function's class) as
>     if it had been implicitly declared, and
> - not have default arguments.

Since the declaration `pair(const pair&) = default;` doesn't have the same declared function type as the copy constructor that would have been implicitly declared, and neither exception applies, the program is ill-formed.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to `= delete` the copy constructor, the proper form is: `A(const A&) = delete;`. See how you forgot that `const`? `pair` can be used with a non-copyable type, even a non-moveable type.

Your instantiation problem can also be demonstrated with:

```
struct A {
    A(A&) = delete;
};

struct B : A {
    B(const B&) = default;
};
```

or...

```
struct B {
    B(const B&) = default;
    A a;
};
```

Basically, `pair` `= default` its copy ctor, and defines it as taking a `const pair&`, but one one of your types defines it to take a non-const &, so the default generation fails since it can't pass it's const& to your non-const&. Even though yours is `= delete`ed, it doesn't matter, it doesn't get that far.

A defaulted copy ctor will effectively be deleted if a member or base class is non-copyable. But in order to figure that out, it has to have a function it is able to call (even if that function is deleted). In these cases, it can't pass a const& to a non-const& so it can't even figure out that you have a deleted copy ctor. Conceivably, something in the standard could be written to accommodate this edge case.